# Topology and Continuity in Real line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

We define continuous functions in topology as an inverse map that takes open sets to open sets. How to see this in light of the basic intuitive Real Line definition of a continuous functions that the map that has no jumps?

Comment: I think you may mean the [preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image/). A good start would be to look at the topology in $\mathbb{R}$ and see how it is defined and how you can get to the [$\epsilon-\delta$](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serlo:_EN:_Epsilon-delta_definition_of_continuity) continuity of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of continuity of $f:X\to Y$ you are refering to is rigorously stated as follows: for each open set $I\subseteq Y$ the [*preimage*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html) $f^{-1}(I)\subseteq X$ is open as well.

The image below shows a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with a "jump", and an example open set $I$ whose preimage is not open. So a continuous function cannot have such jumps.

[image]